# create a view joining multiple tables and another separate tables to a single one

Tags: mysql

I have these tables below

table_1 [ id(primary key, AI), firstname, lastname ]

table_2 [ id(primary key, AI), table_1_id, payment_type, address ]

table_3 [ id(primary key, AI), table_1_id, table_4_id ]

table_4 [ id(primary key, AI), card_number, plan_name ]

What I'm  trying to achieve

1. join table 1 and table 2 where table 2 table_1_id = table 1 id
2. join table 3 and table 4 where table 3 table_4_id = table 4 id
3. joining table 3 and table 4 keeping the table 3 column table_1_id
4. join the new table result from joining table 3 and table 4 to new table result from joining table 1 and 2 per table_1_id

below is what I've tried

```
SELECT 
    `t1`.`id` AS `t1_id`,
    `t1`.`firstname` AS `bill_firstname`,
    `t1`.`lastname` AS `bill_lastname`,
    `t2`.`payment_type` AS `payment_type`,
    `t2`.`address` AS `bill_address`,
FROM
        (`table1` `t1`
        JOIN `table2` `t2` ON ( (`t1`.`id` = `t2`.`table_1_id`) )
        )
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to join the rest, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual table names so we have a better understanding of what you are trying to do and what the relations are.

Answer (score 1):

This would combine  all tables and, show all details.
IF you have only 1:1  relationships you get 1 row per t1.id
If you have between one or more table 1:n relationships, you will get n more Rows per id.

So you will have too Group BY the data with the columns that a in a 1:1 relationsship to t1.id, the rest you have to use [aggregate functions.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

as example fif your have 2 creditcard numbers per t1.id, you have to decide what you will display a GROUP_CONCAT would concatenate the card numbers with an comma

```
SELECT 
    `t1`.`id` AS `t1_id`,
    `t1`.`firstname` AS `bill_firstname`,
    `t1`.`lastname` AS `bill_lastname`,
    `t2`.`payment_type` AS `payment_type`,
    `t2`.`address` AS `bill_address`,
    `t4`.`card_number` AS `card_number`,
    `t4`.`plan_name` AS `plan_name` 
FROM
        (`table1` `t1`
        INNER JOIN `table2` `t2` ON ( (`t1`.`id` = `t2`.`table_1_id`) )        
        INNER JOIN `table3` `t3` ON ( (`t1`.`id` = `t3`.`table_1_id`) )        
        INNER JOIN `table4` `t4` ON ( (`t3`.`table_4_id ` = `t4`.`id`) )
        )
```